# How is input message for SHA-2 padded?

Tags: hash, padding, sha-1, sha-256, sha-2

I read about how is an input message prepared to be hashed by MD4,MD5 or SHA-1:

> Step1 Append padding bits
>
> The input message is "padded" (extended) so that its length (in bits)
>   equals to 448 mod 512. Padding is always performed, even if the length
>   of the message is already 448 mod 512. Padding is performed as
>   follows: a single "1" bit is appended to the message, and then "0"
>   bits are appended so that the length in bits of the padded message
>   becomes congruent to 448 mod 512. At least one bit and at most 512
>   bits are appended.
>
> Step2. Append length
>
> A 64-bit representation of the length of the message is appended to
>   the result of step1. If the length of the message is greater than
>   2^64, only the low-order 64 bits will be used.  The resulting message
>   (after padding with bits and with b) has a length that is an exact
>   multiple of 512 bits. The input message will have a length that is an
>   exact multiple of 16 (32-bit) words.
>
> ... algorithms steps

I read that hose 2 steps are always the same for input messages for MD4, MD4 and SHA-1. How about  SHA-224 / SHA-256 / SHA-384 / SHA-512? How do they 'prepare' input to compute a hash? The same way maybe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SHA-1`, `SHA-224` and `SHA-256` append  the  bit  “1”  to  the  end  of  the message, followed by `k` zero bits, where `k` is the smallest, non-negative solution to the equation `l+1+k ≡ 448 mod 512`, where `l` - message length. In second step they use 32-bit words.

`SHA-384`, `SHA-512`, `SHA-512/224` and `SHA-512/256` use different equation: `l+1+k ≡ 896 mod 1024` and in 2. step use 64-bit words.

If you want to learn more, you should read [Fips-180-4](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf).

Comment: Perhaps you should mention where the $448$ and $896$ values come from (it's to have enough space to fit the message length on 32/64 bits at the end of the padding block)

Comment: So the answer would be "yes, padded using the same method, leaving enough space for the length". The padding is also sometimes used for block ciphers - most people I know simply abbreviate it to "ISO padding" or "bit padding".